# How to merge dataframes of two lists together (same columns)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I have a list of 9 dataframes with the same columnames (called `datalist`)
The dataframes (called L01, L02, ... L09) have all the following structure:

```
$L01
               time pressure    level abs_level
2021-04-22 00:00:00 21.05800 2.146454  12.33845
2021-04-22 00:15:00 21.09500 2.150225  12.34223
2021-04-22 00:30:00 21.04800 2.145435  12.33743
```

```
> str(datalist)
List of 10
 $ L01     :'data.frame':   9792 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ time     : POSIXct[1:9792], format: "2021-04-22 00:00:00" "2021-04-22 00:15:00" "2021-04-22 00:30:00" "2021-04-22 00:45:00" ...
  ..$ pressure : num [1:9792] 21.1 21.1 21 21 21 ...
  ..$ level    : num [1:9792] 2.15 2.15 2.15 2.14 2.14 ...
  ..$ abs_level: num [1:9792] 12.3 12.3 12.3 12.3 12.3 ...
 $ L02     :'data.frame':   9792 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ time     : POSIXct[1:9792], format: "2021-04-22 00:00:00" "2021-04-22 00:15:00" "2021-04-22 00:30:00" "2021-04-22 00:45:00" ...
  ..$ pressure : num [1:9792] 19.4 19.4 19.3 19.3 19.3 ...
  ..$ level    : num [1:9792] 1.97 1.98 1.97 1.97 1.97 ...
  ..$ abs_level: num [1:9792] 12.4 12.4 12.4 12.4 12.4 ...

...
```

I have a similar `addlist` with the same 9 dataframes (also L01, L02, ... L09) of the same structure (same columns and same order), but these data are from a different time period. But I just want to merge the dataframes of the `addlist` to the `datalist`, so that the rows of dataframe L01 of `addlist` are added to the dataframe of L01 in the `datalist`), L02 to L02, and so on for the rest of the dataframes.

So actually very easy... I thought. I can't find the answer clearly on the internet. I was thinking of using rbind, but I don't know how to use that in the context of the two lists.

How can I do this? Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
finallist <- list()

for(i in 1:length(datalist)){
    finallist[[i]] <- rbind(datalist[[i]],addlist[[i]])
}
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but this should work if the lists you want to combine are in the same order and have the same columns

Comment: You aren't assigning the result of `rbind` to anything here; surely you'd need to initialize a "results" list and then store the bound dataframes in that?

Comment: Yep--just edited it and checked it with two objects in my current R environment to make sure it works this time

Comment: Are you sure this works? I think this will overwrite `finallist` in every iteration. Lastly, `finallist` will have output for only last combination.

Comment: Correct again, thanks--just updated to fix that (I used a list of 1 to test)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the base R code below

```
Map(rbind, datalist, addlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
df <- do.call('rbind', your_list)
```

or

```
library(data.table)

df <- rbindlist(your_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr` from the tidyverse, you could try:

```
library(purrr)
map2(datalist, addlist, ~ rbind(.x, .y))
```